# Vue CDN vs CLI concepts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm struggling to understand these concepts: have I got this right? CDN relates to delivering Vue specific "stuff" (code objects and methods I guess?) and you build a Vue site by creating an html file with Vue CDN lines inside to fetch those components (I.e. links to resources or "content")... And then you would host that html on whatever hosting platform you want...

With CLI this is more about getting Vue installed locally, so you can use (vite? Visual studio code? Some other ide?)... Then you can write Vue projects using SFC  and "build" to generate html, js, CSS... Then you can host that html on whatever hosting platform you want...

But what I don't get: at the end of the day the end result for a static front end only site is html, js, CSS which is run on the user's machine... If there is Vue specific code within  tags or JS files... why don't BOTH methods require the "content" delivered in a CDN and a CDN url line? I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental in how these things are conceptualised but thanks for being patient with my (most likely) stupid question

I know there's a lot of info or there, but as a beginner coming from an 'old school' albeit amateur background I struggle with new web development and stack concepts and can't quite find the "angle" I'm looking for

Comment: ... or another way to look at it, if Vue transpiles to js, and user's can run JavaScript on their machines without installing anything apart from a web browser, what exactly is a CDN delivering? If the CLI approach can build a JavaScript file that doesn't require a CDN does that mean it's generating a bunch of boilerplate code, and that's what the CDN is doing too? Just a different way of generating boilerplate (and a CDN just hides it from the user)? If that was the case it would seem more efficient to use CDN for both to save space...

Comment: It's about using preconfigured Webpack setup, which Vue CLI essentially is, vs not using it. Since real-life Vue apps heavily rely on non-spec stuff like SFC and SASS, you're very limited with not bundling an app. You are free to use Vue CDN builds in Webpack as well, as this is the simplest way to share the same Vue copy across multiple Vue apps per page, if that's the case. " it would seem more efficient to use CDN for both to save space" - no.

Comment: i see cool. i still don't get the "why not always include CDN in HTML" thing... am I right that without the CDN then the users javascript includes a bunch of code that could instead have been included in the CDN? Either way the user is downloading the same info, but without CDN they're downloading more javascript from your host? I realise i've probably got the wrong idea here, just asking to try to find understanding, not asking because i have any confidence at all that i have a good point :D

Comment: The amount of downloaded bytes is the same or less when not using CDN, you have the option to tree-shake unused lib parts when building an app, depends on a case of it's significant. While CDN can make it load faster on a client regardless of bytes because of the way they work, but also add a point of failure. Again, there are have two different ideas, CDN lib builds can be used with or without build process. "Vue CDN" is commonly referred as the simplistic way of usage without build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Vue CLI or Vite are the build tools.

The purpose of a build tool is to make the developer's life easier. There are several tasks the build tool can do automatically for you, such as:

- **Building a dev server with Hot Module Replacement** where you can update your code and see the changes automatically reflected on your localhost
- **Compiling and bundling your application**. You can write your template in a `.vue` file. You can write your javascript in `TypeScript`. You can write your CSS in `Sass`. All of them will be compiled and bundled into `.html`, `.js`, and `.css` files that the browser can understand
- **Optimizing your bundle size with tree-shaking.** All of your dead code will not be included in your final bundle

When using **build tool**, you install the Vue package (Vue's code, functions) in your `node_modules` by `npm install` or `yarn add`. These codes will also be bundled into your final `.js` file by the build tool. You likely want to use the build tool when you are building the entire app/website with Vuejs

#### Using Vue from CDN

I do not like the term **Vue CDN**. It might lead to some misunderstandings.

When you [using Vue from CDN](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn), you eliminate the benefits of the **build tools** above. You just add the Vue code in your project via script tag and use it in your javascript. You likely want to use Vue from CDN when you are adding some features with Vuejs to your existing app/website. The app/website might be written in other languages/frameworks like PHP, or Liquid...

If you are starting a new project, just pick the build tool approach. Vite is the best choice for now.